# Angular prerender wrong site title in skype

Tags: angularjs, skype, prerender

I use prerender.io and ng-meta for my angular app, but link in skype have a wrong title:

```
{{ngMeta[:ogTitle]}}
```

FB - all ok.

I thing need add skype bot to prerender but i dont know how i can did it.

Comment: Which middleware are you using? Like you said, you'll just want to add the skype user agent to the list of user agents being checked.